# Binding trigger insert virtual table for INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger that inserts some data into a table without issue. The problem is that in the same trigger I also need to UPDATE OR INSERT an additional table depending on if a matching record already exists. I think I have the UPDATE portion coded properly however I am stumped as to how to perform the INSERT. I get the error `The multi-part identifier "inserted.PatientId" could not be bound`

```
ALTER TRIGGER [trg_Patient_InsertUpdate]
ON  [Patient]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

  -- This inserts data into the PatientDiagnosis table 
  -- regardless of the DiagnosisStatus

  INSERT INTO PatientDiagnosis
  (
    PatientId,
    PhysicianID,
    AdmissionYear,
    DiagnosisStatus
  ) 
  SELECT 
    inserted.PatientId,
    inserted.PhysicianID,
    inserted.AdmissionYear,
    inserted.DiagnosisStatus
  FROM INSERTED

  -- Here I want to UPDATE a second table "PatientTracking" 
  -- if the column "DiagnosisStatus" = 1

  UPDATE pt
  SET pt.DiagnosisReady = 1,
    pt.Report = 'PENDING'
  FROM PatientTracking as pt
  INNER JOIN INSERTED AS i 
    ON pt.PatientId= i.[PatientId] 
      AND pt.PhysicianID= i.[PhysicianID] 
      AND pt.AdmissionYear= i.[AdmissionYear]
  WHERE i.DiagnosisStatus = 1

  -- If the record does not exist in "PatientTracking" then INSERT 
  -- This is where the error is coming from
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PatientTracking (PatientId, PhysicianID, AdmissionYear, DiagnosisReady) 
    VALUES (inserted.[PatientId], inserted.[PhysicianID], inserted.[AdmissionYear], 1)      
  END

END
```

The INSERT statement is where I get error `The multi-part identifier "inserted.PatientId" could not be bound`. How do I make the INSERT statement aware of the `inserted` virtual table?

NOTE * - I am aware of the `MERGE` statement available but it has been my experience that it still has some bugs, specifically it interferes with the Entity Framework binding.

Comment: WAG: inserted isn't viable in that context within this trigger.  Why not save the values you want to insert in local variables *while it is viable*?

Comment: @Will The problem is that the trigger is executed as a set rather than an iteration over each record.

Comment: Well... grab all the inserted records, put them in a temp table, then process?  Triggers give me the bad touch willies.  I wish you luck.

Comment: @will- They give me the "willies" also :) Wait .. is that a pun?

Comment: ... the baaaaad touch ....

Comment: The more I look at my code the more I think I should not use @@ROWCOUNT as this would pertain to a single record. I need to update those records that already exist but insert those that do not already exist.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61e4f5/3 try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is 99.99% correct. Just change your insert statement so that you actually have the inserted table in your query. You don't reference the table in your insert so it is not part of the query.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PatientTracking (PatientId, PhysicianID, AdmissionYear, DiagnosisReady) 
        select i.[PatientId], i.[PhysicianID], i.[AdmissionYear], 1
        from inserted i
    END
```

Comment: This solved the issue with the insert. However, I think my overall logic is wrong in that I need to `UPDATE` those records that already exist in PatientTracking and `INSERT` those that don't already exist and @@ROWCOUNT does not accomplish this. However, this answer does solve the INSERT issue I was having so I am marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use the same select statement,

```
 -- This inserts data into the PatientDiagnosis table 
    -- regardless of the DiagnosisStatus

    INSERT INTO PatientDiagnosis
    (
      PatientId,
      PhysicianID,
      AdmissionYear,
      DiagnosisStatus
    ) 
    SELECT 
      inserted.PatientId,
      inserted.PhysicianID,
      inserted.AdmissionYear,
      inserted.DiagnosisStatus
    FROM INSERTED

    -- Here I want to UPDATE a second table "PatientTracking" 
    -- if the column "DiagnosisStatus" = 1

    UPDATE pt
    SET pt.DiagnosisReady = 1,
      pt.Report = 'PENDING'
    FROM PatientTracking as pt
    INNER JOIN INSERTED AS i 
        ON pt.PatientId= i.[PatientId] 
          AND pt.PhysicianID= i.[PhysicianID] 
          AND pt.AdmissionYear= i.[AdmissionYear]
    WHERE i.DiagnosisStatus = 1

    -- If the record does not exist in "PatientTracking" then INSERT 
    -- This is where the error is coming from
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PatientTracking
                  INNER JOIN inserted 
                  ON inserted.PatientId = PatientTracking.PatientId                      
              )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PatientTracking (PatientId, PhysicianID, AdmissionYear, DiagnosisReady) 
         SELECT inserted.PatientId,
                inserted.PhysicianID,
                inserted.AdmissionYear,1
        FROM INSERTED    
    END
```

Try this SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61e4f5/3

Comment: Would the INSERT statement have access to the `inserted` virtual table?

Comment: Can you please add the full trigger code with definition, Then I will help you in better

Comment: This is not a good approach. This type of trigger will not support multiple row operations.

Comment: use the same select statement, which is you use in previous INSERT statement

Comment: Well now you have changed this to remove the variable declarations which caused to not work.

Comment: @ webworm:- Yes, that INSERT statement have access to the inserted virtual table.